# Query Optimization - Suggestions?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I am hoping someone can help me understand this XML Showplan for a long running query. This query comes from a Crystal Report developed by the software vendor that is very slow running, and I'm trying to convert it to an SSRS report while speeding the query up.

Here is a link to the [Execution Plan](http://www.filedropper.com/executionplan1) - File hosted on File Dropper.

And here is the actual query itself:

```
Select Distinct
CD.desclong [Center],
CD.CenterType,
Sub.Description [SubCenter],
Org.Description [OrgCenter],
CO.CodeID [CenterC],
Sub.CodeID [SubCenterC],
Org.CodeID [OrgCenterC],
Reg.Description [Region],
Reg.CodeID [RegionC],
Rec.CodeID [RecID], 
Rec.Description [RecName],
Rec.NickName [RecNickName],
Acct.AccountID [AcctCharCode],
DM.DriveID,
DM.ExternalID [DriveExtID],
DM.FromDateTime [DriveDate],
dbo.getShiftProductProjectionList(DSD.shiftid)  [ProductProjections], 
dbo.getShiftProcedureProjectionList(DSD.shiftid)  [ProcedureProjections], 
dbo.getShiftMobileList(DSD.shiftid, '1,2,3') [MobileSetups],
LD.LocationName [LocationName],

Case DM.OwnerType
   When 1 Then FSM.DisplayName
   When 0 Then Acct.InternalName 
End [OwnerName], Acct.ExternalID [AcctExtID], SM.ExternalID [SiteExtID],

Stat.StatusText [DriveStatus],
DSD.ShiftID,
DSD.ShiftStart,
DSD.ShiftEnd,
DT.EarlyShiftStart,
DT.LateShiftEnd,
Changes.*,
dbo.getOriginalProcedureProjection(Changes.dsprocshiftid, Changes.dsprocprocedureid) [OriginalProjection], 
(Select Top 1 DescMed From Production.[dbo].QuickCodes where CodeValue = 'ACTEXTIDTAG') [ActExtIDTag],
(Select Top 1 DescMed From Production.[dbo].QuickCodes where CodeValue = 'SITEEXTIDTAG') [SiteExtIDTag],
(Select Top 1 DescMed From Production.[dbo].QuickCodes where CodeValue = 'DRVEXTIDTAG') [DrvExtIDTag],

Case When (Changes.TableName = 'DriveShiftProcedureDetail') Then (Select Top 1 projectionid From driveshiftproceduredetail where uniquekey = Changes.owneruniquekey) else null end as ProjectionID

From
Production.[dbo].rpt_DriveMaster DM
Join Production.[dbo].rpt_DriveShiftDetail DSD on DSD.DriveID = DM.DriveID
Join Production.[dbo].CriticalDriveChanges Changes on (Changes.SourceDriveID = DM.DriveID and Changes.SourceShiftID = DSD.ShiftID and
    Production.[dbo].returnDateTime(year(Changes.ChangeWhen),month(Changes.ChangeWhen),day(Changes.ChangeWhen)) between '01/04/2015' and '01/04/2015')

And
    (
        (
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftProcedureDetail' and Changes.ColumnName='projection')
        or 
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftDetail' and (Changes.ColumnName='ShiftStart' or Changes.ColumnName='ShiftEnd'))
        or 
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftDetail' and Changes.ColumnName='StaffRequested')
        or 
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftDetail' and Changes.changetype='Delete')
        or 
        (Changes.TableName='DriveMaster' and Changes.ColumnName='StatusID' and Changes.NewValue='5')
        or 
        (Changes.TableName='DriveMaster' and Changes.ColumnName='FromDateTime')
        or
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftRoleTimeDetail' and Changes.ColumnName='Lead')
        or
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftRoleTimeDetail' and Changes.ColumnName='TravelTo')
        or
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftRoleTimeDetail' and Changes.ColumnName='Setup')
        or
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftRoleTimeDetail' and Changes.ColumnName='Breakdown')
        or
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftRoleTimeDetail' and Changes.ColumnName='TravelFrom')
        or
        (Changes.TableName='DriveShiftRoleTimeDetail' and Changes.ColumnName='WrapUp')
    )
        and
        (Changes.ChangeWho<>'RMADMIN')
)

Join Production.[dbo].rpt_DriveStatusDef Stat on Stat.StatusID = DM.StatusID
Join Production.[dbo].DriveTimes DT on DT.DriveID = DM.DriveID
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].rpt_CenterDetail CD on CD.CenterID = DM.centerid
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].IDViewRegion Reg on CD.Region = Reg.CodeID
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].IDViewOrgCenter Org on CD.OrgCenter = Org.CodeID
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].IDViewOrgSubCenter Sub on CD.OrgSubcenter = Sub.CodeID
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].IDViewCollectionOp CO on cd.centerid = CO.CodeID
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].IDViewRecruiter Rec on Rec.CodeID = DM.RecruiterID
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].rpt_Accounts Acct on Acct.AccountID = DM.AccountID
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].rpt_FixedSiteScheduleMaster FSM on FSM.DrawID = DM.DrawID
Left Outer Join Production.[dbo].rpt_LocationDetail LD on LD.LocationID = DM.LocationID
Join Production.[dbo].rpt_SiteMaster SM on SM.SiteID = DM.SiteID

Where 
(dbo.returnDateTime(year(DM.Fromdatetime),month(DM.Fromdatetime),day(DM.Fromdatetime)) between '01/04/2015' and '01/04/2015')
or     (dbo.returnDateTime(year(Changes.previousdrivedate),month(Changes.previousdrivedate),day(Changes.previousdrivedate)) between '01/04/2015' and '01/04/2015')
```

Here is the actual execution plan using `Set Statistics XML On`

[Execution Plan](http://www.filedropper.com/executionplan2)

Thanks!

I removed the functions for returnDateTime and used the following instead:

```
-- In the FROM statement
Join Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].CriticalDriveChanges Changes on (Changes.SourceDriveID = DM.DriveID And Changes.SourceShiftID = DSD.ShiftID And Changes.ChangeWhen Between '01/01/2015' And '01/15/2015')
    --Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].returnDateTime(year(Changes.ChangeWhen),month(Changes.ChangeWhen),day(Changes.ChangeWhen)) between '01/01/2015' And '01/15/2015')


-- In the WHERE statement
DM.FromDateTime Between '01/01/2015' And '01/15/2015'
Or Changes.PreviousDriveDate Between '01/01/2015' and '01/15/2015'
--(dbo.returnDateTime(year(DM.FromDateTime),month(DM.FromDateTime),day(DM.FromDateTime)) Between '01/01/2015' And '01/15/2015')
--Or (dbo.returnDateTime(year(Changes.previousdrivedate),month(Changes.previousdrivedate),day(Changes.previousdrivedate)) Between '01/01/2015' And '01/15/2015')
```

The query actually ran slower this way.

Comment: This is an execution plan of comical size. I have never seen something like it.

Comment: Well, like I said: I didn't design it but I'm trying to find a way to improve upon it.

Comment: I see so many dangerous patterns in the plan that you will have to really rework a lot of stuff. The only practical approach will be to target the most egregious problems. Please post the actual execution plan. We need to find out what's taking a lot of time. Hopefully there are very few hot spots. If not - this is going to need some serious work. Fun question.

Comment: Oh, there are function calls as well. Wonder what's hidden behind those...

Comment: Thanks usr, I have edited the original question to include the execution plan.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use the `returnDateTime` function everywhere? It is being invoked millions of times and it prevents index usages (assuming suitable indexes exist). For example AuditDetail returns 600k rows to be filtered down to 7k by this function. That work could disappear if properly indexed. This problem is all over the place.